# Check if string-sliced characters in Pandas column contain another string

Tags: python, pandas, string

So I'm trying to get characters 0:8 of a string contained in a Pandas column and check that that column contains a given value. Using this code:

```
def findCourse(url, course):
    df = pd.read_html(url, flavor="html5lib")[0]
    # this gets csci 141 and 141L (BUG)
    return df.loc[df['COURSE ID'].str[0:8].contains(course)]
```

I get this error (because .str converts to a series and so we can't call .contains):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\wm-scheduler\scheduleGenerator.py", line 52, in <module>
    findEveryCourse()
  File "C:\Projects\wm-scheduler\scheduleGenerator.py", line 17, in findEveryCourse
    df = findCourse(url, course)
  File "C:\Projects\wm-scheduler\scheduleGenerator.py", line 36, in findCourse
    return df.loc[df['COURSE ID'].str[0:8].contains(course)]
  File "C:\Users\jbcal\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5487, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slice on `.str` accessor returns a Series, which doesn't have the `contains` method. In order to call `contains` method on it, you should chain another `.str` accessor after. i.e. `df['COURSE ID'].str[0:8].str.contains(course)`